# OBSOLETE - SOStacked: Stack Exchange iPhone client

Tags: app, obsolete, iphone

## OBSOLETE - App is not available anymore and website is down.

### Screenshots

[image]
[image]
[image]

### About

Awesome feature set.

- Powerful search, beautiful display
- Pick your favorite and ignored tags
- **Log into your account**, track your reputation!
- See your incoming answers, comments and other messages in your inbox.
- Stay tuned. Pick your favorite tags to build a custom questions stream.
- Bounty hunter? Dedicated section to see all featured questions.
- Questions and answers are displayed in a mobile-friendly style, with nice code formatting.

#### License

Available on the Apple App Store for $2.99

#### Download

[SOStacked iTunes page (web)](http://itunes.apple.com/app/sostacked/id427708024?mt=8) (not available anymore)

#### Platform

iOS 5.0 and later
(includes support for iPhone 5)

### Contact

Any comment is welcome here or by email: sostacked_app [at] me.com
Website: http://sostacked.jldagon.me (down as of at least February 2019)

---

#### Planned evolutions

- iPad version
- More to come with evolutions of the Stack Exchange API: ask questions, post answers...

Comment: I like it. But I'm not sure why you just didn't merge the User and Users. Seems a little repetitive. A couple more feats would be awesome. But it's nice. I like it. I was just looking for something like. So, Thanks for your hard work. I want to add that's it's clean. And I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

Great app. I am having a problem though - whenever I open the Reputation, app simply exits. iPhone 4, iOS 6.1.3, just downloaded from AppStore so I guess it's latest version.
Could not find a website so decided to drop a line here.

Comment: Hi, I need to find some time to fix it and release an update but it's definitely on my list. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What I really miss though is to vote for answers and comments.